# Sort Order in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that gets sorted at three levels. My question is why does my output look different when I use the Order By in my SQL as opposed to when I remove it from the SQL and add the Order by as a part of the Tablix ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options for ordering output in ssrs.

- SQL ordering is the lowest precedence
- Ordering of the tablix would be the next lowest
- Ordering in the group would take precedence over all other.

You also have datatypes to throw into the mix that could affect the way output is sorted in each of the layers  (ie SQL will sort using its collation)

But its a combination of these sort order that will finally determine the output of your report.

if you want more detail about your *specific* problem, you'd need to post more information  (sql query, screenshots of tablix sort order, screen shot of group sort order, output of the differences)